# MVC 5 - Returning an unordered list to the server, along with a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 / Bootstrap application. On one of the pages, I have a number of fields all bound to the model associated with the page. However, I also have a simple unordered list which always starts out empty and the user can then add items to it. They do this by entering some text into a type ahead field. Once the user finds what he/she is looking for, he/she can click a button and have it added to the unordered list. Any number of items can be added to the list. All of this works fine.

My question is how I can get the contents of the unordered list posted back to the server along with the rest of the form contents, since the unordered list isn't part of the model?

Comment: See if [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to skin this cat:

A) Add a collection to your model (which really should be a ViewModel, and not a domain model) to hold those items

B) In your button's click handler, create a hidden input field that conforms to the ASP.Net Wire Format: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

If you had a collection of orders, you should end up generating controls like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Orders[0].Id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="Orders[1].Id" value="2" />
```

Note sequential ordering is important, if you start removing items, you'll need to re-sequence your name values.

Comment: You can avoid problems with interrupted or unorderred sequences by adding another <input type="hidden" name="Orders.Index" value="1" /> for each item, as Phil Haack describes in his post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/
This is especially useful when you try to delete items from the list.

Comment: @Hannes Very interesting, I'll consider this as an option in future perhaps as opposed to the Regex gymnastics I typically perform.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - I'm drawing a blank on how I would add a collection to my model that represents the unordered list. That would be the preferred solution I think.

Comment: List<T> would work, as would ICollection<T>. There are examples in the referenced blogs, it's pretty simple once it clicks.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - Thanks. I should have been more clear. What I was drawing a blank on is how this List<T> gets represented in the HTML.

Comment: The wire format is the representation. When you build each `li`, you must also create a "buddy" hidden input as described above. You need to add two elements to the `DOM` now.

Answer (score 0):

There couple of ways to work it out.
 If you don't want to add to model, what I would prefer to do you can:

1. Directly access item that were posted via `Controller.Request` property;
2. You can post this items separately via Ajax request, and handle them in different controller action.